# Disble facebook login button while logging in

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I want to disable facebook login button while logging in with facebook. Is there any ways to do that ?
Here is my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
window.fbAsyncInit = function(){

                FB.init({appId: 'MY_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {

                    if (response.status === 'connected'){
                        FB.api('/me', processFBToken);
                    }
                    else if(response.status === 'not_authorized'){
                        FP.login();
                    }
                    else{
                        FB.login();
                    }
                });
            };

            $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
            $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js');

            //process the callback response
            function processFBToken(response){
                if(response && response.authResponse && response.authResponse.accessToken){

                    var token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    $.post('/user/login', {facebookToken : token}, function(data){

                    })
                }
            }
        })
    </script>
```

And in my html

```
    <fb:login-button size="large">
              Login with Facebook
    </fb:login-button>
```

I also have another button for normal login.

```
<button type = 'submit' class = 'btn btn-primary' id = 'login-submit-btn'>Login</button>
```

How can I disable that button also when i click 'login with facebook' button. Really appreciate for your help

Comment: you can do like this
if(login session is set){echo facebook button}, i am not sure about your sessions which will store  when user login though facebook and your programming language so i am giving you rough idea

Comment: No what i mean is like when i click the facebook login button, that button should be disbled so the user can not click many times

Comment: yes so you can do like i mention above, check if user is login ,dont show the button